# SQL for remaining non-matched rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Let's say I've got two tables:

Table1:

| post_id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data |

Table2:

| post_id | user_id | read |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true |

And I'm selecting data as:

```
SELECT
    t1.post_id,
    t1.text,
    t2.user_id,
    t2.read
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.post_id = t1.post_id
    AND t2.user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

That would obviously net me one row with [post_id = 1, text = data, user_id = 1, read = true].
What I want is to "generate" rows on fly with default values for other user entries that don't actually exist in table2.

To be precise, this is what I would like as a result:

| post_id | text | user_id | read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | data | 1 | true |
| 1 | data | 2 | false |
| 1 | data | 3 | false |

Comment: You also need a cross join with user table. And change table2 join to left join

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh Both, application can connect to either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate all pairs of posts and users, then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT table1.post_id, users.user_id, COALESCE(table2.read, false)
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS users(user_id) -- you can use an actual table here
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.post_id = table2.post_id AND users.user_id = table2.user_id
```